# Position of word in sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence

> **History is an inevitably important** and compulsory subject in the
>   curriculum of many countries, and some people argue that learning
>   about local history is more crucial than memorizing historical world
>   events.

Am I right to write "History is an inevitably important..."? , or should I just need to write:" History is inevitably an important subject..."?

I am confused with the position of words in sentences. I really appreciate for your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**inevitably** is an adverb, so it can either describe verbs, adjectives, or other adverbs.

In your two examples, it is being used to describe different words in the sentence.

> History **is inevitably** an important subject.

Here, it is describing the verb **is**.

> History is an **inevitably important* subject

Here, it is describing the adjective **important**.

Both, sound technically grammatical, but I prefer the first. It is much more common for **inevitably** to refer to the verb, especially the verb, **to be**.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter, no wonder I feel something "not natural" in my sentence which is the second case that you mentioned.